# Use Cordova InAppBrowser in form POST method

Tags: vue.js, cordova, post, inappbrowser, quasar

I am developing an application in VUEJS using quasar framework to develop IOS/ANDROID app.
I want to open external webpage in my cordova application.
I have following form that i am using to post data to external payment gateway.

```
<form action="https://myUrl.com" method="post" id="myForm">
                <input type="hidden" name="MERCHANTID" v-model="paymentDataPost.MERCHANTID" >
                <input type="hidden" name="APPID" v-model="paymentDataPost.APPID" />
                <input type="hidden" name="APPNAME" v-model="paymentDataPost.APPNAME"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="TXNID" v-model="paymentDataPost.TXNID"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="TXNDATE" v-model="paymentDataPost.TXNDATE"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="TXNCRNCY" v-model="paymentDataPost.TXNCRNCY"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="TXNAMT" v-model="paymentDataPost.TXNAMT"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="REFERENCEID" v-model="paymentDataPost.REFERENCEID"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="REMARKS" v-model="paymentDataPost.REMARKS"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="PARTICULARS" v-model="paymentDataPost.PARTICULARS"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="TOKEN" v-model="paymentDataPost.TOKEN"/>
                <br>
              </form>
```

And I was submitting this form in my methods after confirmation.

```
document.getElementById('myForm').submit()
```

This code works fine in web browser. When I tested my application in IOS platform, external website was not opening from my application.

So, I did some research and got to know about cordova-plugin-inappbrowser. Then I changed my above code to below one.

```
methods: {
  async confirm () {
    var myForm = '<form action="https://uat.connectips.com:7443/connectipswebgw/loginpage" method="post" id="myForm">' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="MERCHANTID" v-model="paymentDataPost.MERCHANTID" >' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="APPID" v-model="paymentDataPost.APPID" />' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="APPNAME" v-model="paymentDataPost.APPNAME"/>' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="TXNID" v-model="paymentDataPost.TXNID"/>' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="TXNDATE" v-model="paymentDataPost.TXNDATE"/>' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="TXNCRNCY" v-model="paymentDataPost.TXNCRNCY"/>' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="TXNAMT" v-model="paymentDataPost.TXNAMT"/>' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="REFERENCEID" v-model="paymentDataPost.REFERENCEID"/>' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="REMARKS" v-model="paymentDataPost.REMARKS"/>' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="PARTICULARS" v-model="paymentDataPost.PARTICULARS"/>' +
            '<input type="hidden" name="TOKEN" v-model="paymentDataPost.TOKEN"/>' +
            '<br>' +
            '</form>' +
            '<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById("myForm").submit()<script/>'
    var pageContentUrl = 'data:text/html;base64,' + btoa(myForm)
    window.open(pageContentUrl,
            '_blank',
            'hidden=no,location=no,clearsessioncache=yes,clearcache=yes'
          )
  }
}
```

New window opens, but url is blank, and post data is not available as well.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: It's likely CSP related issue: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#content-security-policy

Comment: How do I fix this?? I didnot understand the documentation.